# problemas com loop infinito usando PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: php, pdo

**Minha Query**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE algumvalor=2 LIMIT 1";
```

**Está entrando em loop infinito aqui**

**Como faço usando** `while`?

```
  while($row_data=$conn->executaQuery($sql)) 
  {
      var_dump($row_data);    
  }
```

**Com `for` funciona**

```
$row_data = $conn->executaQuery($sql);


foreach($row_data  AS $dados){

    var_dump($dados);

}
```

**Classe de conexão e busca**

```
public function executaQuery($sql){
    $db = $this->conn;
    $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    return $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: Sua consulta sempre retorna a mesma linha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `foreach` percorre todos os elementos `array` de dados que retorna até o final e para quando não tiver mais dados.

Já o `while` vai ficar sempre fazendo a verificação e do jeito que você fez ele sempre vai fazer a consulta novamente no banco de dados, chamando a função.

Um exemplo de como poderia utilizar o `while`

```
$row_data = $conn->executaQuery($sql);
$i = 0;

while($i < count($row_data)) { 
    var_dump($row_data[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```